# Initialize only once

Tags: python, execfile

I've got a couple of scripts (named one.py and two.py) circularly calling each other using execfile. The one.py (which is the one to start) has some code (initialize) that I would like to execute only once.

**I would like to continue using execfile** if possible

How could I achieve this ?

```
#one.py
def initialize():         
    # initializing

initialize()

# do the main work

execfile('two.py')

----------------------------

#two.py

# do some work

execfile('one.py')
```

Comment: Move the code from one.py into execfile.

Comment: `def(initialize):` should be `def initialize():`?

Comment: Either create a third file which does the initialization and calls two.py, or use some storage (e.g. database, temporary file), which stores the state "was intialized" or "was not initialized".

Comment: Why do you want to use [**`execfile`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile)?

Answer (score 2):

Why not create a third file zero.py which starts the initializing and then executes one.py who then executes the loop.

```
 #zero.py
 def initialize():
# do some initializing

initialize()

execfile('one.py')
```

On another note there should probably be better ways to run your code then this loop of execfile.

Comment: Unfortunately the initialize function calls other functions and uses variables that reside in one.py

Comment: Could you import one.py in zero.py and then use these variables and functions?

Comment: Then create a temporary file and save your state there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could define a class that runs your tasks?

For instance, something like:

```
from itertools import cycle

class TaskRunner(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.tasks = ('one.py', 'two.py')

        # do some initializing

    def run_continuously(self):
        for filepath in cycle(self.tasks):
            execfile(filepath)


# to run:
task_runner = TaskRunner()
tsak_runner.run()

----------------------------

#one.py

# do the main work (without initializing)


----------------------------

#two.py

# do some work

----------------------------
```